# Group by multiple column and perform custom aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe  example given below.

```
   hour minute value
   0    0      10
   0    5      20
   0    10     30
   0    15     50
   0    20     10
   0    25     55
   1    0      55
   1    5      50
   1    10     10
   1    15     20
   1    20     30
   1    25     40
   1    30     50
```

.... like this for every hour for a day. I want to take mean,stdev of  every hour and for every min and multiple each with the actual value for that hour and min as two new column. So the final dataframe would look like below.

So for 0 hour & 0 min the mean is mean(10,55) & stdev(10,55)
 the value for new columns  for 0 hour and 0 min would be mean(10,55)*10 & stdev(10,55)*10
and the value for new columns for 1 hour and 0 min would be
 mean(10,55)*55 & stdev(10,55)*55
same way it needs to iterate for all hour and min and aggregate

```
  hour minute value mean*value stdev*value
   0    0      10   325        318
   0    5      20   700        424
   1    0      55   1787       1750
   1    5      50   1750       1060
```

Currently i am doing iterate over rows first by hour and then by minute and doing the calculation of adding value against each.

```
for hour in df.hour:
  for minute in df.minute:
    trim_df = df.loc[(df[hour] == hour) & (df[minute] == minute)]
    mean = trim_df [value].mean()
    stdev = trim_df [value].std()
  for index,row in trim_df.iterrows():
       df.at[index, "mean*value"] = row["value"]*mean
       df.at[index, "stdev*value"] = row["value"]*stdev
```

My approach is taking huge time I am trying to use pandas group by feature but not able to convert this logic.

Comment: Can you show what you did with groupby? You should be able to do this with groupby and transform

Comment: nothing concrete I am new with pandas group by

Comment: @D14 I'm not sure i understand - your initial dataframe is already unique on (hour, minute) pairs. how are you going to multiply them mean by hour with the value of that hour - in your example there are 6 possible values for hour 0, how would you pick which one to use?

Comment: @Stael is right, do you want the mean for the hour or the mean for the minute?

Comment: i have given only for 2 hrs actual dataframe is for 24 hrs so for there will be 24 value for every 0,5 so on minutes. Mean will of those 24 values and then multiplied with actual against those minutes. Hope I am able to clarify

Comment: it would for minutes

Comment: I'm trying to imagine why you could possibly want that, but it's pretty simple - i'll put in an answer i a little while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.groupby(...).transform('mean')`to return a series with the mean of each group:

```
import pandas as pdf

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['hour', 'minute', 'value'], data =   

[[ 0,    0,     10],    
[0,    5,      20],   
[0,    10,     30],   
[ 0, 15,     50],    
[0,    20,     10],    
[0,    25,     55],    
[1,    0,    55],    
[1,    5,    50],    
[1,    10,   10],    
[1,    15,     20],    
[1,    20,     30],    
[1,    25,     40],    
[1,    30,     50]])


df['mean_value'] = df.groupby(['minute'])['value'].transform('mean')*df.value

df 

=>     hour  minute  value          mean_value
0      0       0     10                325.0
1      0       5     20                700.0
2      0      10     30                600.0
3      0      15     50                1750.0
4      0      20     10                200.0
5      0      25     55                2612.5
6      1       0     55                1787.5
7      1       5     50                1750.0
8      1      10     10                200.0
9      1      15     20                700.0
10     1      20     30                600.0
11     1      25     40                1900.0
12     1      30     50                2500.0
```

Do the same thing with `.transform('std')` to get the standard deviation series.

Comment: i was going to suggest https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html but essentially the same thing.

Comment: @TMrtSmith isn't it possible to have a custom function that can be used with transform

Comment: @stael - Don't think .agg gives a series in the same length as the original df?